# Run Azure Cloud App on local QA server without Visual Studio

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration

We use continuous integration to local QA servers, and for normal ASP.NET web sites we just use MSDeploy or similar to deploy to QA servers, and run the applications in IIS.

For Azure Cloud Apps, we would like to do the same, but I can't understand whether or not this is a supported scenario - and if so, if there's a way to do it without actually installing Visual Studio with the Azure SDK on the QA server.

Several guides (like [this one](https://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/how-to-deploy-application-to-windows-azure-compute-emulator-with-csrun/)) mention `cspack` and `csrun` to start the environment locally, but this all seems dependent on having Visual Studio and the Azure SDK. There's also a guide [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/) which I'm not sure is even describing what I'm looking for; it seems rather complicated.

**Is there a way to run Azure Cloud Apps on QA servers without Visual Studio? Or is this how it's supposed to be done?**

Comment: Are these QA servers on azure too?

Comment: @HariHaraChandan "local QA server" sounds like an on-premise non-Azure server.